# Proof that the characteristic polynomial of a matrix can be expressed as a sum of the matrix's determinant and scaled powers of its eigen values

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, characteristic-polynomial

In the book, [Introduction to Computational Linear Algebra](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Introduction-Computational-Linear-Algebra-Nassif/dp/1482258692), the authors state the following:

> For any matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^n$, its characteristic polynomial, $p_\text{A}(\lambda) = \text{det}(A - \lambda I)$ can be expressed as
>
> $p_\lambda(A) = |A| + \sum_{i=1}^n c_i\lambda^i$, where $c_i \in \mathbb{R}$ and $i = 1, 2, \dots , n$.

I don't understand how the above equation was derived. Can someone please help me with the proof?

Comment: Are you familiar with, say, the Leibniz expansion of the determinant? This will show you have a polynomial in $\lambda$ of degree $n$. Then take $\lambda=0$.

Comment: @blargoner Sorry. I am not familiar with the Leibniz expansion. I took Linear Algebra some 15 years ago in my UG education, and we barely did enough of the basics and nothing more. I shall much appreciate if you please expand your comment as a longer answer with derivations and/or suitable references.

Comment: For sums, use `\sum`, not `\Sigma`.

Comment: What is $p_\lambda$ ? If $p=\operatorname{charpol}(A)$ then $p(A)=0$.

Comment: @K.defaoite yes. $p_\lambda(A)$ is the characteristic polynomial of $A$ parameterised by the algebraic variable $\lambda$. Therefore, $p_A(A) = 0$ by the Cayley-Hmilton theorem, I understand. But I am just wondering about the expansion of the characteristic polynomial in terms of sum of its determinant and a polynomial with powers of its eigen values

Comment: So by $p_\lambda (A)$ you actually mean $p_A(\lambda)$. Ok.

Comment: Well, obviously $p_A(0)=\det A$ so the polynomial can be written as $p_A(x)=\det A+\sum_k a_kx^k$. That's all